# Android, insert Event with CalendarContract crashes calendar app on Sony Xperia

Tags: android, calendar, crash, sony, sony-xperia

I'um using CalendarContract to insert a custom local (not synced) calendar and events. It's working on all devices, but not on Sony Xperia (4.4.4). Code for inserting a new local calendar

```
    final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, calendarName);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, calendarName);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, calendarDisplayName);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xeeff0000);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    //cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, calendarName)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
            .build();

    //context.getContentResolver().insert(calUri, cv);
    try {
        Uri result = context.getContentResolver().insert(calUri, cv);
        Long calId = Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
        Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_KEY, "==> add Calendar OK: " + calId);
        return calId;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_KEY, "==> add Calendar FAILED: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

The calendarName ist the app package name. Code for inserting Events:

```
     long eventID = 0;

    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate.getTime());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate.getTime());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, allDay ? 1 : 0);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

    try {
        Uri uri =   context.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        Log.d(DEBUG_KEY, "EVENT ADDED: " + eventID);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_KEY, "EVENT-ADDED FAILED: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

There are no errors oder exceptions. The debug console display the correct inserted calendar and event id. On all devices i can see, display and edit the events in the calendar app.

On Sony Xperia devices the events are showing in the calendar app. But tapping on the event for showing/editing, the calendar app crahes with the follwing error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.EventInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ...
>   Reading a NULL string not supported here.